# How do I clean marks from masking tape glue on my windows?

Tags: windows, cleaning

During the Hurricane Sandy, we placed tape on our windows in case the glass would break. The problem is, after removing the tape, it left a disgusting glue mark that it became impossible to remove. It has been a few years now. I hope somebody can help me here, see the pictures:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WD-40 says it removes adhesive residue

Research: http://wd40.com/uses-tips/construction/removes-adhesive-residue

Answer (score 4):

Use something like Goof Off or Goo Gone to dissolve the solvent, or something with orange oil in it, and then scrape it off. You might have to repeat a couple of times.

BTW, taping windows provides no additional protection during a hurricane. Don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

You might have luck with a razor blade.

[image: razor blade]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/28-510_2_rgb_4.jpg))</sub>

This is what's commonly used by mechanics, to remove registration and inspection stickers from vehicle windshields.

***Warning:** Don't use razor blades on windows with films or special coatings.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use a combination of methods which were suggested by longneck and Tester101 to completely remove the residue.

A window scraper tool uses the type of blades in Tester's picture. Using the tool will make it easier to scrape with instead of just a blade.

After the majority of it is scraped off, then you can use a solvent to remove the leftover residue. If you don't have Goo Gone or Goof Off around the house, isopropyl alcohol will also do the job.